# How can i display .docx and .pdf file in webview?

Tags: android, android-webview, document, docx

How can i display docx and pdf file in WebView not using url?

Any idea to read document file in android?

Comment: did u get an answer to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
String myPdfUrl = "http://example.com/awesome.pdf";
String url = "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + myPdfUrl;
Log.i(TAG, "Opening PDF: " + url);
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.loadUrl(url);
```